# Graph Generated By Chart.js Has Entirely Different Coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, django, chart.js, web-development-server

I am trying to sketch out a real-time graph in Django and I deployed Chart.js functions' to help me out. What I did was to return a dictionary containing the points that I would like to plot within the script tag. The keys of the dictionary will be assigned to the "label" field while the values to the "data" field.

However, the points that were plotted out were completely different from the dictionary that I provided and on top of that extra points kept appearing out of nowhere which didn't seem to cease until I manually stopped the process.

Below is a portion of the html code:

```
<div class="centerpane">
    
   
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas> 
</div>
<script > 
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  'use strict';
  var main_graph_points = "{{ main_graph_points }}"; //the dictionary
  
  var graphData = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: Object.keys(main_graph_points),
          datasets: [{
              label: 'main graph',
              data:Object.values(main_graph_points),
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(73, 198,230, 0.5)',
                  
              ],
              
              borderWidth: 1
          }],
          options:{
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
              type: 'category',
              }]
            }
          },
    },
      
      
      
      
  }
  
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx,graphData );
  
  
  
  
  
  
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/mysite/");
  
  socket.onmessage =  function(e){
  
      var djangoData = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log(djangoData);
      document.querySelector("#app").innerText = djangoData.value;
  }</script>
```

---

```
//contents of the dictionary
main_graph_points={20: 59.96601343154907, 24: 59.89738027254739, 28: 59.9285344282786, 32: 59.92363293965656, 36: 59.96989806493124, 40: 59.9742821852366, 44: 59.98536904652914, 48: 59.97467199961344, 52: 59.981049299240105, 56: 59.96619900067648, 60: 59.94627912839255, 64: 60.038129488627135, 68: 60.05686759948728, 72: 60.0296068191528, 76: 59.96951897939045, 80: 59.92006580034892, 84: 59.990370273590095, 88: 60.05626598993939, 92: 60.067607561747, 96: 60.00708500544241, 100: 59.97309843699136, 104: 59.9625798066457, 108: 59.946976502736405, 112: 59.96854305267334, 116: 60.00266710917153, 120: 59.99812404314678, 124: 59.9947758515676, 128: 60.01623233159381, 132: 60.05894184112546, 136: 60.005687077840136, 140: 59.99874432881674, 144: 59.99069054921468, 148: 59.96476372083027, 152: 60.001704692840526, 156: 59.95250264803568, 160: 59.977914492289216, 164: 59.98758951822918, 168: 60.01008351643885, 172: 60.01819769541427, 176: 60.06649494171134, 180: 60.02984921137493, 184: 60.03375212351465, 188: 60.03094037373873, 192: 60.01178423563648, 196: 60.05387783050534, 200: 60.03662347793581, 204: 59.989521106084176, 208: 59.91725405057272, 212: 59.96652205785114, 216: 60.01453717549625, 220: 59.964253107706696, 224: 59.905698299407966, 228: 59.88801956176758, 232: 59.96659398078921, 236: 59.99791781107586, 240: 60.02731959025054, 244: 60.044821103414, 248: 60.10827223459879, 252: 60.08096615473428, 256: 60.11190891265874, 260: 60.10422627131141, 264: 60.0104133288066, 268: 60.02395788828528, 272: 60.0046308835348, 276: 59.98100678126018, 280: 59.92317438125611, 284: 59.86979643503825, 288: 59.849180777867616}
```

Below is a picture of the output that I received:
Received output

[image]

But the expected to trace is supposed to look like this(ignore the vertical lines, only the purple trace is of interest over here):
Expected output

[image]

Do you guys know where is the possible source of error? Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: removing `type: 'category',` may help.

Comment: Oh I did that initially but it had no effect, thanks tho @uminder